# getting this Warning Initialization of pointer of type 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    - (id) firstResponder: (UIView *) navView {
            for (id aview in [self allSubviews:navView]) {
                if ([aview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [(UITextField *)aview isFirstResponder]) {
                    return (UITextField *)aview;
            }
            else if ([aview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] && [(UITextView *)aview isFirstResponder]) {
                return (UITextView *)aview;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

getting an error : Initialization of pointer of type 'id' to null from a constant boolean expression in iOS 8.

Comment: replace "return NO" with "return nil".Coz "NO" is not object.
And id is datatype for any Object in Objective C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
return NO;
```

to:

```
return nil;
```

(`NO` is a boolean literal and the compiler is complaining about it being converted to type `id` in order to be returned).

Comment: Note that `NO` is actually `0` and `nil` is also `0`, so `return NO;` will execute perfectly fine, but the compiler is complaining because it thinks you made a mistake.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Yeah it's a compiler *warning*, as the OP states.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the implementation a bit as below...

In this you need not to worry about `NO`, `nil`, `null` etc, even no warning for `id` or `integer` will be thrown by compiler.

```
- (id) firstResponder: (UIView *) navView {
    UIView *view = nil;
    for (id aview in [self allSubviews:navView]) {
        if ([aview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [(UITextField *)aview isFirstResponder]) {
            view = (UITextField *)aview;
        }
        else if ([aview isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]] && [(UITextView *)aview isFirstResponder]) {
            view = (UITextView *)aview;
        }
    }
    return view;
}
```